# Is there any difference between ./ and / in <script> src attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, path, filepath, src

Given the following project structure:

```
/root
  /static
    script.js
  page.html
```

This will '*import*' `script.js`, into the HTML file:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/static/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

this will, as well:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./static/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

I am wondering:

1. Is one way preferred over the other?
2. Are there any cases, when `/` and `./`, in she `src` attribute of `<script>` will behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I am not super experienced in JavaScript, but I'll let you know what I know.

```html
[...]
<script src="./static/script.js"></script>
[...]
<!--This would reference files in the current folder (where the webpage itself is stored)-->
```

```html
[...]
<script src="/static/script.js"></script>
[...]
<!--This would reference an absolute path within your webserver, and cannot change dynamically based on from where you load it.-->
```

Generally speaking, I'd go for `./` when you load it from a file in your current folder (and/or server), whilst doing `/` seems like an external reference to me, which is also not dynamic. If you happen to move the file (if it was in the same directory as your page), I think JavaScript would also reference the new file instead of complaining about the old one.

I cannot guarantee that any of the info above is correct as I am not a really good JS-Developer, but at least this should help you figure out the syntax a little more.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, They both are different.
You are not able to see as the `index.html` is already in your root directory.
If there is a `.html` file inside a directory. Then you can see the difference.

./ This gives a relative path from the file you are accessing it

/ This  gives an absolute path from the root of your directory

If this is the directory structure

```
/root
 /static
  script.js
 /page
  index.html
```

Then, you won't be able to use ./ as it won't find `script` folder in the `page` folder

So, if you have a complex directory structure use ./ i.e. `relative` path, and if you have a plain structure / i.e. `absolute` path would be good. For better practice, the relative path is preferred over an absolute path.
Hope, this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

`./` is a relative path or the current directory where your asset will be served.

`/` is an absolute path or the root path from where your asset will be served.

Answer (score 0):

`./` is a relative path linking to the current directory.

`/` is an absolute path linking to the root directory.

You can find more information [here](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).