# Why path in <script> src, starting with single slash results in error?

Tags: javascript, html, path, filepath, src

I have this project structure:

```
/root
  /static
    script.js
  page.html
```

This code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/static/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

results in:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///static/script.js”.
```

Why is that? I would expect it to search for `static` folder in current directory (i.e. `root`).

Comment: under which path is page.html

Comment: because such path does not exist

Comment: The question is why it said `static/canvas.js` instead of  `/static/script.js` ?

Comment: If you remove the slash doesn't it work? Or else add .. before it? page.html is in the same folder as static, so when doing /static he might be looking for a folder in page.html

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina waht do you mean? The error message does say `/static/script.js` - in `file:///static/canvas.js` `file://` is the protocol and the target is `/static/canvas.js`

Comment: You call `script.js` but your error msg says `canvas.js` error.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina, sorry for confusion, it is just my mistake (copy&pasted the wrong message). The script is called `script.js`, the error says `script.js` as well (fixed it in the question too).

Comment: @JensW, it finds the script if I remove the slash (i.e. `<script src="static/script.js">`. But my understanding is it should work with the slash, as well. And I want to understand why it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is there because there is no such file in your system's root directory.

This can easily be solved by serving your `/root` folder and accessing the `page.html` via that server.

You can find a list of static file servers [Here](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255).

Going with `Node.js`'s [http-server](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255#http-server-nodejs).

Open a terminal in your '/root' directory and run the following commands:

`npm install -g http-server`
`http-server -p 8000`

Then you can access your `page.html` file at `http://localhost:8000/page.html`

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case the error is produced, because I have just opened `page.html` in a browser on my machine (i.e. I have not served it via server), thus **`/` is interpreted as local machine's root**. If I have served the project, then `/` would be interpreted as project's root, and there would be no error.

---

A little more elaborate explanation/illustration.

Given this structure:

```
/root
  /static
    script.js
  page.html
```

Here are what different paths (in `page.html`) will refer to:

- `/` — root directory, it **might** mean `/root`, but also might mean the root of current environment (see explanation at the beginning of this answer)
- `./` — current (the one where `page.html`  resides) directory, it just so happens that it is `/root` in this case

  - it is worth mentioning that `./` [can be omitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591243/8554766) altogether, when referencing some file in current directory; so `./static/script.js` is equivalent to `static/script.js`

---

I have derived understanding needed for this answer, from:

- [Aayush's answer to current question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072330/8554766)
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56071861/8554766), to another question of mine
- [**comments** to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591336/8554766)

Answer (score 0):

If you have any directory into your root folder and your **js** file into that then you have to mention path only with folder name then file name like:

```
folder-name/filename.js
```

because into web browser there is no need to add forward slash into starting of file path 
browser so it by self